# firebase deploy typescript wants to access remote library

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In a firebase project I imported a npm library from a private git project. Like this:

```
npm install --save git+https://tronpd@bitbucket.org/name/name.git
```

When I run firebase deploy, the CLI wants to access the repo again, while all code is in node_modules. To my humble opinion, it wouldn't be needed to request access to there repo's.

Is there an option to deploy cloud functions in the old vanilla JS style? Because with in the /lib folder, the javascript functions are already built there.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase CLI doesn't upload your `node_modules` to Cloud Functions, but instead uploads your `package.json` so that Cloud Functions can request the module when it builds a container for your code.

If the module isn't needed in your runtime, you can install it without passing `--save`. If the module isn't mentioned in your `package.json` Cloud Functions won't install it the container(s).

If the module is needed on the containers, then there's no way to keep the Firebase CLI from inspecting it. In that case you might want to look into Cloud Run, which gives you more direct control over the containers that your code runs in.

Comment: Okay, clear, thanks for the explanation. But there is no way to deploy cloud functions that are already built locally? Just like when you start a javascript project and can just deploy .js files?

Comment: You could use local dependencies only. That means you don't put anything in the package.json, and manage those dependencies yourself.